# File Upload Javascript + php

Tags: php, javascript, upload

Olá, preciso enviar alguns arquivos via post para tratar no PHP. Porém, quero enviar via post pelo JavaScript, passando outros parametros no submit e conseguir tratar no PHP. Do jeito que eu to fazendo, eu não recebo nenhum $_FILE, só funciona o $_FILE no php quando eu passo apenas ele como parametro no post, sem os demais parametros.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('#upload').on('click', function () {
                var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
                var form_data = new FormData();
                form_data.append('file', file_data);

                $.post({
                    url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
                    dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: {action: 'enviar', form: form_data}, //quero passar assim, mais de um parametro, o form_data seria o file. 
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#msg').html(response); // display success response from the PHP script
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        $('#msg').html(response); // display error response from the PHP script
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Single File Upload Example using PHP</h1>
    <p id="msg"></p>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <button id="upload">Upload</button>
</body>
```

E no php não consigo retornar o $_FILE, pq desta forma não reconhece, a nao ser que eu passe apenas data: form_data. 
Mas preciso passar os demais parametros junto.

Comment: E por que não inclui o valor de `action` no próprio `form_data`?

Comment: ja tentou recuperar assim $_POST['form'] ?

Comment: sim, adicionando no form_data deu certo, obrigada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você consegue enviar o valor de `action: 'enviar'` pelo próprio objeto `FormData` que você possui, basta fazer:

```js
var form_data = new FormData();

form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.set('action', 'enviar');
```

E para enviar, você pode colocar apenas `data: form_data`, igual da forma que funcionou.

Isso gerará no corpo da requisição HTTP o campo `action` com o valor `'enviar'` e no PHP poderá fazer `$_POST['action']` normalmente.

Comment: Assim deu certo, obrigada.( acho que não consigo votar porque meu usuário é novo)